# Foreach command with table

Tags: shell, unix, awk, foreach

I have a data which looks like this

```
cat 1.txt 

abc def ghi
jkl lmn opq
rst uvw xyz
```

i want to use its contents in another command :

```
foreach c (`cat 1.txt | awk '{print $1}'`)
cat $c/$1 | sed "s,patter1,pattern2,g" > ! $c/$2
end
```

**where $c=abc , $1 =def , $2 = ghi      in first case,
then $c=jkl , $1 =lmn , $2 = opq      in second case and so on till end of 1.txt**

Can someone suggest, how can i do it?

I have tried below :

```
foreach c (`awk '{print $1}' 1.txt`)
foreach d (`awk '{print $2}' 1.txt`)
foreach e ( `awk '{print $3}' 1.txt` )
echo $c $d $e 
end
end
end
```

Comment: What you want to do at the end?

Comment: I want to use this table to set variables and use those variables in below command:
foreach c (`cat 1.txt | awk '{print $1}'`)
cat $c/$1 | sed "s,patter1,pattern2,g" > ! $c/$2
end

Comment: No, you want probably something else, explain it with own words

Comment: i wan to set $c=abc , 
                   $1 =def , 
                   $2 = ghi in first case, 
then use  $c $1 $2 in another command

since these are to accessed from a file 1.txt, whose content i have given in question